# 'Find' and 'unique' in an array of user-defined class objects (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, oop

After dabbling in C# I'm now keen to use some OOP in Matlab - to date I've done none!

Let's say that I define a class for a data object with a handful of properties...

```
classdef TestRigData
    properties
        testTemperature
        sampleNumber
        testStrainAmplitude
        sampleMaterial
        rawData
    end

    methods
        % Some constructors and data manipulation methods in here
    end
end
```

...where 'rawData' would be a m-by-n array of actual experimental data, and the other values being doubles or strings to help identify each specific experiment.

If I have an array of TestRigData objects, what would be the best way of finding the indices of objects which meet specific criteria (e.g. testTemperature == 200)? Or getting all the unique values of a property (e.g. all the unique sample numbers in this collection).

If they were arrays of their own, (myNewArray = [3 5 7 22 60 60 5]) it would be easy enough using the find() and unique() functions. Is there a class I can inherit from here which will allow something like that to work on my object array? Or will I have to add my own find() and unique() methods to my class?

Comment: off topic, but consider making your class a [handle-class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html), that way you get reference semantics and avoid the excessive copying of the possibly large `rawData` matrix

Comment: I would say that's very on topic, @Amro! That's very much what I was trying to figure out with, "Is there a class I can inherit from..." And indeed `rawData` winds up being pretty good sized, or at least there will be many of them. This object array will be created from order of 100MB of raw ASCII data.

I will have to investigate this more, thank you.

Comment: truth is internally MATLAB is a bit smarter than that with regards to making copyies. For value-classes, `obj2=obj1` will not immediately copy the data, but wait until you actually first modify one of the objects (lazy [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write)). Furthermore, each property of the object can be separately shared, so you can modify one property while the others are still shared with the original object. For handle-class `obj2=obj1` of course simply creates another reference to the same underlying variable, so any changes in `obj2` will also reflect in `obj1`

Comment: so if you pass value-class objects as input to functions, where the objects are intended as read-only, you dont have to worry about MATLAB making unnecessary copies (as long as you dont modify the objects, unfortunately MALTAB has no `const` keyword to enforce this). You could confirm this by inspecting the output of `memory` before after creating copies of objects holding large data: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/internal-matlab-memory-optimizations/

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an ID value (a hash value in the general case) to `TestRigData` objects and store it as a new property. You can then extract all ID values at once to a cell array, *e.g* `{yourarray.id}` (or `[yourarray.id]` if the ID values are scalars), allowing you to apply `find` and `unique` with ease.

Adding your own `find` and `unique` is definitely possible, of course, but why make life harder? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of creating this as a handle class  (rather than value class) is something I need to think about more in the future... after having put together some initial code, going back and trying to change `classdef TestRigData` to `classdef TestRigData < handle` seems to be causing issues with the constructor.

Bit unclear of how I would go about using a hash value unique to each object... but the syntax of extracting all values to an array is ultimately what got me in the right direction.

Getting a new object array which is the subset of the original big data array conforming to a certain property value is as easy as:

`newObjectArray = oldObjectArray([oldObjectArray.testTemperature]==200);`

Or for just the indices...

`indicesOfInterest = find([oldObjectArray.testTemperature]==200);`

Or in the case of non-scalar values, e.g. string property for sample material...

`indicesOfInterest = find(strcmpi({oldObjectArray.sampleMaterial},'steel'));`

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer, but rather an addendum to your question. Also, if my answer proved to be useful, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the voting buttons.